# SQL Dropdownlist search with downloadable csv file of query in Yii

Tags: php, sql, csv, yii

My task is to create a form that has a drop down list in which I will use to search for content within the database.

For example: The count of Suppliers of Materials per Region.

My plan is to create a form that has a submit button and once it is submitted, it will use the values selected from the dropdown list in order to execute the correct sql command.

My question is how I should approach the controller for such a task that does the following:

When submit is clicked,
the controller does the following:

-creates sql command
-saves it into a dataProvider
-then executes the query into a csv file that automatically makes the file downloadable.

Also, am I supposed to create a folder in the "views" named "reports"? And should I put new action within the controller that supports the model for suppliers, materials, and region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using extensions, look at the ECSVExport code for Yii.

From the documentation:

> - You can also do this now:
> - $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM track_test LIMIT 10");  *
> - $csv = new ECSVExport($cmd);
> - $csv->setOutputFile($outputFile);
> - $csv->toCSV();